# Django ORM связь один ко многим с несколькими таблицами, без raw

Tags: django, orm

Модель:

```
class Mark(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Марка", unique=True, null=True)

  #...


class Model(models.Model):
  mark = models.ForeignKey(Mark, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Марка")
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Модель", unique=True, null=True)

  #...


class Car(models.Model):
  vin = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

  #...

class Image(models.Model):
  car = models.ForeignKey(Car, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path, verbose_name="Фото")

  #...
```

Как сделать следующий запрос с Django ORM, но без raw:

```
query = "SELECT c.*, m.name mark_name, JSON_ARRAYAGG(img.image) image FROM incarcatalog_car c \
LEFT JOIN incarcatalog_mark m ON m.id=c.mark_id \
LEFT JOIN incarcatalog_image img ON img.car_id=c.id \
WHERE c.id>%s \
GROUP BY c.id;"
queryset = Car.objects.raw(query, [id])
```

Left джойны сделал, но это для таблиц Mark и Model, а как соединить с Image не понял:

```
queryset = Car.objects.select_related("mark", "model").all()
```